# Grails trouble saving object id

Tags: sql, oracle, grails, groovy

id is present in the params but does not save to the db. for example

```
[book.id:1, comments: good]
```

comments will save to db but book.id does not.

I need to figure out how to save params.book.id into the db column BOOK_ID that was created from the hasmany/belongsTo relationship.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you looked inside the database? I think it save the id...

Comment: Yes, the scaffolding will save the id but It will not save from the controller. I guess I am not sure how to assign params.book.id. I didn't realize it was saving as ID in the scaffolding. I am going to have to edit my question I suppose. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default value attribute of each  element will be the result of a toString() call on each element. Setting it as optionKey allows the value to be a bean property of each element in the list.

Kindly change the select to

```
<g:form action="review">
  <g:select name="book.id"
    from="${item.Book.list()}"
    value="${book?.id}"
    />

 <g:textField name="bookreview" value="${params?.bookreview}" /><br>
```

kindly refer the below link

[Grail example with optionkey](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have overwritten `toString`, therefore your books are always rendered by `name` and not `id`. If you remove your `toString()` method you will see the expected results.

If you want your select box work with the name, just add `optionValue="name"`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that I had misspelled a crucial parameter inside my domain. So the domain was expecting x and it was getting y. Thus the id was always null. It took me a while to spot it, and I was perplexed because I had previously successfully implemented ids in another project. Grails has some jira issues also that make one consider other possibilities, but this time it was my mistake.